# IE7 list on top of another

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on IE7, but the list is on the top of the submenu, is there a way to bring it on the top?
it works fine on IE8 or plus but not IE7.
wish someone could help. Many thanks

[here](http://jsfiddle.net/xvDbv/16/) is the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `display:inline-block`. IE 7 doesn't interpret this correctly and needs hacks to actually show an element as an `inline-block`.

In your select CSS statement add this:

```
.select {
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* IE 7 hack */
    zoom:1;          /* IE 7 hack */
}
```

Alternatively you could create an IE7 only stylesheet and use the above without hacks.

This solves the problem in IE7 but you may want to change the Z-index's of some elements to stop the drop down list displaying underneath the bottom select box.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xvDbv/18/)

Comment: Thank you David. you are right, I did once before, but forgotten. :-)